Spring data JPA pagination memory usage
Let's say I want to fetch the data from database and transform them and display in UI
As many said The main reason to do pagination is not really because it makes sense to only display a few entries in the UI at once. Instead, pagination allows you to only transfer the necessary entries from large data sets. But the problem is Let's say I have 30 K records and I only show 1000 entires at UI at once using paginantion the problem arises when user filters or sorts or serahc anything is shown (We have 18 columns with search and filtering on all) in this case I need to deal with whole database to do this and Paginantion does'nt help here or is there a better way ?
Currently we load the entire dataset and do filtering, searching and sorting it works fine but how to do it with pagination.

Please take the tour, read How to Ask, and then post a proper minimal reproducible example with all relevant details. Also, read this Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

You have the Informed badge, which means that you [supposedly] took the [tour], but did you read [ask]? [Edit] your question and post your current code - that loads the entire data set - then someone may be able to show you how to change it so that it supports pagination, Asking for someone to post sample pagination code is not really a suitable question for SO. Again, refer to [ask].

Now if only you could use the database to do the filter, searching and sorting, instead of retrieving everything in-memory and do it there. There is a thing called SQL of for JPA, JPQL use it to write queries to do the filtering. Don't do things like that in memory, use the database for that and if you do behold paging also still works. \

Yes, there is a more efficient way to address this issue. You can solve it using the JPA Criteria API.
You might want to look into topics such as Specification and Criteria Builder. These concepts will help you resolve the problem effectively.
Consider the below User example:
folder structure
UserController:-
//UserController
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

import com.practice.entity.User;
import com.practice.search.SearchCriteria;
import com.practice.service.UserService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import org.springdoc.core.converters.models.PageableAsQueryParam;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }


    @PostMapping("/batch")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> createUsers(@RequestBody List<User> users) {
        List<User> savedUsers = userService.saveUsers(users);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedUsers);
    }

    @PostMapping("/search")
    @PageableAsQueryParam
    public Page<User> searchUsers(@RequestBody SearchCriteria searchCriteria, @Parameter(hidden = true) Pageable pageable) {
        return userService.search(searchCriteria,pageable);
    }

}

UserService:-
//UserService

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.practice.entity.User;
import com.practice.repository.UserRepository;
import com.practice.search.SearchCriteria;
import com.practice.search.SearchSpecification;

@Service
public class UserService  {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }


    public List<User> saveUsers(List<User> users) {
        return userRepository.saveAll(users);
    }


    public Page<User> search(SearchCriteria searchCriteria, Pageable pageable) {
        SearchSpecification searchSpecification=new SearchSpecification();
        searchSpecification.add(searchCriteria);
        return userRepository.findAll(searchSpecification,pageable);
    }

}

UserRepository:-
//UserRepository

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.practice.entity.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

}

UserEntity:-
//UserEntity

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;
    private String email;
}

CustomBuilder.java:-
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;

public class CustomBuilder {

    public Predicate buildPredicate(SearchCriteria criteria, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<?> root){
        String value= criteria.getValue();
        return switch (criteria.getOperation()){
            case GREATER_THAN -> builder.greaterThan(root.get(criteria.getKey()), value);
            case LESS_THAN -> builder.lessThan(root.get(criteria.getKey()), value);
            case NOT_EQUAL -> builder.notEqual(root.get(criteria.getKey()), value);
            case EQUAL -> builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), value);
            case CONTAINS -> builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(criteria.getKey())), "%" + value.toLowerCase() + "%");
            // can perform as many as operations which are included in CriteriaBuilder class
            default -> throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Operation not supported");
        };
    }
}

FilterOperation.java:-
public enum FilterOperation {
    CONTAINS,
    EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL,
    GREATER_THAN, LESS_THAN
}

SearchCriteria.java:-
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String  key;
    private String value;
    private FilterOperation operation;
}

SearchSpecification.java:-
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import com.practice.entity.User;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;


public class SearchSpecification extends CustomBuilder implements Specification<User> {

    private final List<SearchCriteria> searchCriteriaList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        searchCriteriaList.add(searchCriteria);
    }
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for(SearchCriteria searchCriteria: searchCriteriaList) {
            predicates.add(buildPredicate(searchCriteria,criteriaBuilder,root));
        }

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}

Lets say i have users database which has 39 entries User's Data
Scenario 1:- Filtering the Users who has age > 30 and Sorting in Ascending Order
swagger-ui-1
swagger-ui-2
//response
{
      "totalElements": 25, //from 39 users, 25 users age>30 
      "totalPages": 5, 
      "size": 5,
      "content": [
        {
          "id": 26,
          "name": "Zoe Harris",
          "age": 31,
          "address": "456 Cedar Dr, Star City, CA",
          "email": "zoeh@example.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "Olivia Wilson",
          "age": 31,
          "address": "987 Cedar Blvd, Central City, CO",
          "email": "oliviaw@example.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 38,
          "name": "Scarlett Turner",
          "age": 32,
          "address": "456 Dogwood Dr, River City, LA",
          "email": "scarlettt@example.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 18,
          "name": "Harper Allen",
          "age": 32,
          "address": "987 Dogwood Dr, River City, LA",
          "email": "harpera@example.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "Benjamin Harris",
          "age": 33,
          "address": "654 Cypress St, Hub City, MD",
          "email": "benjaminh@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "number": 0,
      "sort": {
        "empty": false,
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false
      },
      "first": true,
      "last": false,
      "numberOfElements": 5,
      "pageable": {
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 5,
        "sort": {
          "empty": false,
          "sorted": true,
          "unsorted": false
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
      },
      "empty": false
    }

Senario-2 : Filtering the Users whose names consists of value "ia" , sorting in descending order
swagger-ui-1
swagger-ui-2
//response
{
  "totalElements": 7,
  "totalPages": 2,
  "size": 5,
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "William Anderson",
      "age": 44,
      "address": "789 Spruce St, Blüdhaven, AZ",
      "email": "williamanderson@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Sophia Martinez",
      "age": 36,
      "address": "456 Willow Ave, Keystone, FL",
      "email": "sophiam@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 39,
      "name": "Sebastian Morris",
      "age": 37,
      "address": "987 Olive St, St. Roch, SC",
      "email": "sebastianm@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Olivia Wilson",
      "age": 31,
      "address": "987 Cedar Blvd, Central City, CO",
      "email": "oliviaw@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Mia Young",
      "age": 25,
      "address": "321 Cherry St, Happy Harbor, IN",
      "email": "miayoung@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "number": 0,
  "sort": {
    "empty": false,
    "sorted": true,
    "unsorted": false
  },
  "first": true,
  "last": false,
  "numberOfElements": 5,
  "pageable": {
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 5,
    "sort": {
      "empty": false,
      "sorted": true,
      "unsorted": false
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  },
  "empty": false
}

The above approach can resolve your problem .... You can filter as many as operations using CriteriaBuilder.....
I hope this information is helpful....
